# Cytoscape's concentric layout edge's length manipulation , may be using cola.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, cytoscape.js

Is there any way by which I can manipulate the edge lengths of graphs in concentric layout ?
 I know cola.js(cola layout) provides manipulation of edge length in cytoscape.js, but I want to use concentric layout and also manipulate the edge's length or cola.js's layout and get the concentric layout.

Please suggest on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Layouts that allow setting relatively precise edge length are generally physics simulations.  You won't get regular shapes, like concentric circles, with them.

You could approximate distance by setting the levels, though this won't be exact -- because distances will vary on different sides of the circles.  The levels are regularly spaced, as long as there is no overlap.

So, you can disable overlap correction and set the levels and level widths according to the relative distances you want.  You can use a smaller sweep (maybe ~90 degrees) to make the association of level-to-distance a bit closer.

Comment: I want to manipulate the next level on the basis of nodes in the current level. As I have 4 nodes in the current level, so for the next level I want to plot the nodes connecting to each of the nodesin the 360/4 = 90 degrees for each, so deciding the arc for each of the child modes on the basis of the parent node in the previous level and no. of nodes in the previous level. What would you guys suggest, should I edit the concentric layout or try with my custom layout.

Comment: You're not constrained to running one layout for all elements in the graph, and you can use layouts in succession.  So, you could use multiple circle layouts, specifying the angular sweep allowed for each level.  This would let you handle each node and its successors iteratively, and you could iterate via nodes.bfs().